# Sum of consecutive numbers for a row vector and storing them in that position

Tags: matlab

I have 1e6 values of P. I want to write a code that finds the mean of a set of random numbers and stores them  in that order eg. The second position of the vector lets call mu_P should be p1+p2/2. The 10th postion of P10 should be sum of (P1 to P10)/10. The 1e6 position should be (P1 to P1E6)/1E6.I am a beginner in matlab

```
n_r=1e6;
p=randn(n_r,1);
mu_p= zeros(n_r,1);
for i=2:n_r
    mu_p(i)=p(i)+p(i-1)/i;
end
```

My output only sums the current and previous number at each step and those not consider all the earlier numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are just taking averages of two consecutive numbers from `p` and storing them into `mu_p`, which is exactly the wrong output you are getting.

For the average of all numbers from index [1 to n], I would suggest the following.

```
mu_p = cumsum(p)    % built-in function for cumulative sum. 
denom = 1:n_r    % denominator for each index in mu_p = # terms till the index
mu_p = mu_p ./ denom    % elementwise division
```

**Example**

Input: 
`p = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];`

Output: 
`mu_p = 1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000    5.0000`

Comment: Thanks very much. I am new to matlab hence i don't  know much about the inbuilt function. Is there any function  that does exactly  what the cumsum is doing but this time i want to calculate  the standard deviation?

Comment: For variance you can use similar procedure. Once you have ```mu_p```, square the elements of ```p``` first, take ```cumsum(p)```, divide that by ```denom``` element-wise, and finally subtract ```mu_p``` elementwise squared.

Comment: Also, do accept my answer if it was helpful. That lets the community know the question has been answered properly.

Comment: I have accepted the answer. I am a little bit lost about the concept of the variance. Thanks

Comment: I am using the  formula for variance (unfortunately I cannot show it using MathType on this forum). Which part exactly did you not understand?

Comment: Why do i have to  square p first? Shouldn't i rather subtract p from mu_p . Then square it and then divide by denom elementwise?

Comment: Oh. I am using an alternate form of the same. Check this [website](https://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/science-fair/variance-and-standard-deviation). Scroll down like halfway

Comment: Pu_sqr=(Pu).^2;                                                                      
r=cumsum(Pu_sqr);
std=r./index-mu_Pu; Thanks . Like this ?

Comment: I didn't understand the last line. I mean something like this ```std =(r./denom) - mu_p.^2```

Comment: Yes  that's what i meant on writing.  I tried to do an edit but it wasn't going through.